# Laravel update query error using query builder with comma separeted values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I am getting the below error in the laravel controller when I update 4 columns with comma-separated values without quotes which are coming from the request

```
Request payload:
column1 : one,two,three
column2 : six,seven
column3 : eight,nine
```

Code

```
<?PHP
function run(Request $request){
    $column1 = $request->get('column1');
    $column2 = $request->get('column2');
    $column3 = $request->get('column3');
    $save = DB::table('tableone')->where('primaryclm', '1')
                ->update(['column1' => $column1,'column2' => $column2,'column3' => $column3]);
}
?>
```

Error:

> SQL error (SQL: update `tableone` set `column1` = one,two,three
> ,`column2` = four,five,six
> ,`column3` = seven,eight
> where `primaryclm` = 1)

Kindly help with this issue.

Comment: Simply add quotes around the values.

Comment: add you migration file for better clarification

Comment: What are the datatypes of $column1,2,3. please check dd($column1) output and also post "tableone" schema.

Comment: Also you have not included the full sql error often it will say Missing column, invalid value with a code, this makes it way easier to debug, right now we only get the generic error.